# Shopify add new index.html page with url https://myshopifyshop/index.html

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working with external tracking service. They sent my index.html file, which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//path.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

They want us to upload this file to shopify and sent them the url to it. The url should look like this https://myshopifyshop/index.html. I couldn't find any article how to upload or create new blank html page with .html extension. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an html page that will follow the root url of your site.

But you can upload a html page as an asset and link that asset as a page.

Example url will be:

`https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/*****/*****/t/4/assets/index.html`

---

But I don't think that this will do you any good, since tracking services requires you to track the current site and not a dummy file that no one will ever open.

It's highly possible that the only important part is the script and everything else is not needed.

So you actually may need to add the script in your `layout/theme.liquid` file and ignore the rest.

Please contact the the tracking service and let them know that you are not using a static HTML site, but a Shopify one and what steps should you follow.

Comment: shopify doesn't allow me to upload files with extension .html